# swipe menu from left in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

all,  I am working on Reactjs/redux web project, I have a responsive menu, which opens from side by clicking the burger menu button, the menu is working fine but I want to add the functionality by which user can open the menu by swiping from the left, can anyone help me to how to proceed with the swipe function, my code is attached below, thanks in advance

```
       class SidePanel extends React.Component {
    state: {
        showModal: Object,
        showAccountSubMenu: boolean,
        showCategorySubMenu: boolean,
    };
    toggleModal: Function;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            showModal: {
                currency: false,
                country: false,
                language: false,
            },
            showAccountSubMenu: false,
            showCategorySubMenu: false,
        };
        this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
    }
    handleClickOutside() {
        if (this.props.showMenu) {
            this.props.toggleMenu(false);
        }
    }
    toggleModal(type) {
        if (typeof this.state.showModal[type] !== 'undefined') {
            const showModal = this.state.showModal;
            showModal[type] = !showModal[type];
            this.setState(showModal);
        }
    }

    renderAccountSubMenu() {
        const myAccLink = '/account';
        const links = {
            cart: '/cart',
            userAccount: myAccLink + '/profile',
            userOrders: myAccLink + '/orders',
            userAddresses: myAccLink + '/addresses',
            userPayments: myAccLink + '/payment',
            userReturns: myAccLink + '/returns',
            userStoreCredits: myAccLink + '/store-credits',
        };
        return (
            <div>
                <button
                    className={styles.menuLink}
                    onClick={() => this.setState({ showAccountSubMenu: false })}
                >
                    <Icon
                        name={this.props.language === 'ar' ? 'angle-right' : 'angle-left'}
                        className={styles.iconReturn}
                    />
                    <span className={styles.menuText}>
                        {I18n.getText('sidebar.back-to-main-menu', {}, 'Back To Main Menu')}
                    </span>
                </button>
                <p className={styles.title}>{I18n.getText('header.user-account', {}, 'My Account')}</p>
                <a className={styles.menuLink} onClick={this.props.logout}>
                    <Icon name="power" className={styles.icon} />
                    <div className={styles.menuText}>
                        <div>{I18n.getText('header.sign-out', {}, 'Sign Out')}</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        );
    }

    render() {
        const links = {
            signin: '/login',
            signup: '/login/signup',
        };
        if (this.props.currentPath) {
            links.signin += '?redirect=' + this.props.currentPath;
            links.signup += '?redirect=' + this.props.currentPath;
        }
        return (
            <div className={styles.container} id="sideMenu">
                <div className={styles.content}>
                    {/* HOME / SIGN IN SIGN UP OR ACCOUNT TRIGGER START */}
                    {(!this.state.showAccountSubMenu && !this.state.showCategorySubMenu) &&
                        <div className={styles.mainMenu}>
                            <LocaleLink
                                className={styles.menuLink}
                                to={'/'} onClick={() => this.props.toggleMenu(false)}
                            >
                                <Icon name="home-o" className={styles.icon} />
                                <div className={styles.menuText}>{I18n.getText('sidebar.home', {}, 'Home')}</div>
                            </LocaleLink>
                            {this.props.user
                                ? <button
                                    className={styles.menuLink}
                                    onClick={() => this.setState({ showAccountSubMenu: true })}
                                >
                                    <Icon name="user" className={styles.icon} />
                                    <span className={styles.menuText}>
                                        {I18n.getText('header.user-account', {}, 'My Account')}
                                    </span>
                                    <Icon
                                        name={this.props.language === 'ar' ? 'angle-left' : 'angle-right'}
                                        className={styles.iconArrow}
                                    />
                                </button>
                                : <div>
                                    <LocaleLink
                                        className={styles.menuLink}
                                        to={links.signin}
                                        onClick={() => this.props.toggleMenu(false)}
                                        >
                                        <Icon name="user-signin" className={styles.icon} />
                                        <div className={styles.menuText}>
                                            {I18n.getText('sidebar.sign-in', {}, 'Sign In')}
                                        </div>
                                    </LocaleLink>
                                </div>
                            }
                            <div className={styles.seperator} />
                        </div>
                    }
                    {/* HOME / SIGN IN SIGN UP OR ACCOUNT TRIGGER END */}

                    {/* ACCOUNT SUBMENU START */}
                    {this.state.showAccountSubMenu && this.renderAccountSubMenu()}
                    {/* ACCOUNT SUBMENU END */}

                    {/* CATEGORIES START */}
                    {!this.state.showAccountSubMenu && <CategorySelector
                        categories={this.props.categories}
                        language={this.props.language}
                        toggleMenu={(showMenu) => this.props.toggleMenu(showMenu)}
                        toggleCatSubMenu={(showMenu) => this.setState({ showCategorySubMenu: showMenu })}
                    />}
                    {/* CATEGORIES END */}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You code is not readable!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-easy-swipe

Comment: hey @AbdennourTOUMI, i have to make short code or intent in proper way ?

Comment: I just Googled "javascript swipe left to right eventlistener" and found all kinds of good stuff. Check that out.

Comment: @wali Hello, are you able to solve it?